# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Hello i'm new in implementing Spring REST Web Service what's the cause of my error.

Here's my code

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/message/{regID}/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String getMessage(@PathVariable String regID, @PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello Alvin!" + regID + " " + name;
    }
```

i want to call it using the web browser but i failed to successfully invoke it but when i call single parameter of may another RequestMapping is Successfully completed.. Here is the RequestMapping that i successfully called

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id) {
    List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    listOfCountries = createCountryList();

    for (Country country : listOfCountries) {
        if (country.getId() == id)
            return country;
    }

    return null;
}
```

> Or How can i implement multiple parameter for my RequestMapping..?

Comment: The only difference I see is the return type. Maybe String can't be serialized. Have you tried to return `String` in `getCountryById` method? Just for test if it works. Return, empty string for instance.

Comment: but in my some other RequestMapping methods with and single parameters it work but if i have two or more it's not working is there something i need to be configure or what with my service..?

Comment: give a try by removing headers.

Answer (score 1):

The chances are that you're using the `InternalResourceViewResolver`, in which case the methods that return `String` will interpret the returned valued as a view name that will be searched inside the locations designated in the view resolver. Your *no mapping found* probably refers to that the framework can't find a view name that matches what you're returning

As your intention seems to be to return the text only you should simply additional map your method with `@ResponseBody` which will in turn add your text to response body instead of interpreting it as a view name, so

```
@ResponseBody 
public String getMessage(@PathVariable String regID, @PathVariable String name)
```

Otherwise, your mapping is just fine

Answer (score 0):

I you have more than one path variables, you need to sepecify the identifier in `@PathVariable`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message/{regID}/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String getMessage(@PathVariable("regID") String regID, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return "Hello Alvin!" + regID + " " + name;
    }
```

Comment: No need - if the URI template variable name matches the method argument name you can omit identifier detail.